# What is the meaning of the singular values?

Tags: control, control-system

I am studying MIMO control systems, and I have seen that the Bode plot of these systems is composed by the various singular values. But I have not clear the meaning of these sigular values. What I have understood is that they are related to the various inputs, but it is not very clear to me.

Can someone help me understand this concept?

[EDIT] I have found this example of a distillation process:

[image]

where are present the maximum and minimum singular value.

[EDIT 2] Here is a paper where the distillation process is discussed and it is also present a similar frequency response : [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271478517_Identification_of_an_ill-conditioned_distillation_column_process_using_rotated_signals_as_input)

Comment: Um, I've never seen a Bode plot of a complete MIMO system, as all practical MIMO systems are built in a way that the individual channel can be considered flat (otherwise we couldn't do a singular value decomposition of the MIMO channel and thus, there'd be no singular values). So, can you link to a publication that shows a MIMO bode plot, and show one of these plots here?

Comment: thanks for the graphics, I also asked for a link to the publication.

Comment: It is not really a publication, but more an extract from a book, I think it is the Multivariable Feedback Control: Analysis and Design from Skogestad. Here it is: http://folk.ntnu.no/skoge/presentation/thai05/13_MIMO_systems_ch3+4+6.pdf. If you prefer a full paper I have also found one which I will attach to my question